# save libreOffice file with java

Tags: java, url, save, libreoffice

I need to save a file with libreOffice (libreWriter), but for some reason, it doesn't seem to work when the path uses File.separator, i.e, the top one works, and the bottom doesn't. Does anyone know why or if there is a workaround? I want my code to be windows/mac compatible.

```
xStorable.storeToURL("file:///C:/Users/testDoc.doc", propertyValues);
xStorable.storeToURL("file:///C:"+File.separator+"Users"+File.separator+"testDoc.doc", propertyValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this code is running on a Windows host; I am *guessing* that this method `storeToURL()` simply doesn't work with the path that your second example would create.

You see, your first URL goes "file:///C:/"; whereas the second example will turn into "file:///C:\" on a windows machine.

In other words: the 2nd way would create a "correct" windows file path string; but that is probably *not* what this method actually expects!

Comment: You're right. It's a bit strange that this method only accepts a linux/mac file separator though. Oh well, at least the workaround of replacing \ with / in a path is simple and seems to work.